# Xamarin.Forms, how to find compatible version of Android Support library with my current Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-support-library

As Xamarin document says it's not possible to update Android Support library to the last version unless Xamarin.Forms supports it, as I can see there is update version `25.1.1` for Android support library, I'm not sure if my Xamarin.Forms accepts it! so how can I find the compatible version to each Xamarin.Forms version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `monoandroid10` framework, `Xamarin.Forms` is locked to a particular Android Support version but assuming you are targeting  framework `monoandroid70` / `monoandroid71`, Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193 and up are now locked to a **minimun** Android Support version only.

- Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.180 (and prior) = `MonoAndroid10` support only

  - Each release was locked to a **single** Android Support version
  - Android Support version = 23.3.0 (only) (Package dep. range: **`[23.3.0, 23.3.0]`**)
- Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193 = First `MonoAndroid70` supported version

  - Minimun Android Support version = 23.3.0 (Package dep. range: **`[23.3.0, )`**)

So that means `Xamarin.Forms` versions 2.3.3.193, 2.3.4.224, 2.3.4.231, & 2.3.5.233-pre1 (latest) you can use **Android Support 23.3.0 and above** for monoandroid70+.

Note: Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193 and newer also support the MonoAndroid10 framework and when used against that framework, each Forms version is still locked to a single Android Support version.

Note: Some future version of Forms will increase the minimum Support level version when the Android-based renderers require newer support features.

As a quick online reference, you can always look at the Nuget dependencies for a particular Forms version

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms

Or grab the Nuget v3 packed json and use `jq` to parse it for the Nuget dependency range (I used to auto-generate/publish a version table, but with the newer frameworks it is not really needed anymore)

```
curl -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/xamarin.forms/page/2.3.3.193/2.3.5.233-pre1.json | gunzip | jq '.items | .[0] | .catalogEntry | .dependencyGroups | .[0] | .dependencies | .[0] | .range '

"[23.3.0, )"
```